# devtools::check() report error due to rJAVA

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, devtools, rjava

In Rstudio, I run `devtools:check()` in my project, and the following error occured

> Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>         call: library.dynam("rJava", pkgname, libname)
>         error: DLL 'rJava' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?

Before this error occur, I am pretty sure I successfully installed `rJava` using `install.packages('rJava',type='source')`, now I run `.libPaths()` and it returned

```
[1] "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"
```

The `rJava` library I installed is in `C:\Users\sunxd\Documents\R\win-library\3.3`, and after I copy that into`"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"` it still does not work.

I could load `rJava` by `library('rJava')` anyway.

It seems that the problem is with different architecture, and I wonder why there should be different architecture on only one machine?

```
** running examples for arch 'x64' ... OK
Examples with CPU or elapsed time > 5s
           user system elapsed
tuneParams 5.72      0    5.83
** found \donttest examples: check also with --run-donttest
* checking for unstated dependencies in 'tests' ... OK
* checking tests ...
** running tests for arch 'i386' ...
  Running 'run-base.R' [17m]
Warning message:
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD BATCH --vanilla  "run-base.R" "run-base.Rout"' had status 1
```

Comment: Can you load the rJava package via `library(rJava)`?

Comment: yes, definitely I could load rJava via library(rJava)

Comment: Make you Java is in your PATH so that when RStudio is doing it's checking from the command line it can also find Java

Comment: To confirm Carl's suggestion, could you include the output of `Sys.getenv("PATH")`

Comment: @Osssan and @ Carl, Sys.getenv("PATH") returns C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;

Comment: now I add this "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_101\\bin"